# Rewrite 1 level of url directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm looking to rewrite the first directory of a url string and have the rest of the request still work.

Eg: I want it so when a user clicks the link for : `/products/category/item.php`
it actually grabs the file of : `/shop/category/item.php` But still shows as `/products/category/item.php` as the URL

This will be dynamic so it should be something like `/products/$` `/shop/$1` I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need mod_rewrite. [when to avoid mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html).

Mapping url directories to file directories is a basic functionnality of Apache handled by the mode **[mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html)** (which is quite certainly already present for you).

So basically you have the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) and [AliasMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) directives. In your case the first one is enough:

```
Alias /products/ /path/to/web/document/root/shop/
```

The mapping is done only server-side so the url seen by the end user is never modified.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)  shop/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^products/(.+)$ /shop/$1 [L,NC]
```